# Criar uma arraylist em uma classe e utilizá-la em outra

Tags: array

Meu problema é o seguinte eu tenho uma classe que contém uma arraylist, eu preciso utilizar os objetos dessa arraylist em outra classe. Estou tendo problemas para criar. Sou novato e não mexi com isso ainda.

Comment: Qual linguagem?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Adicione sua tentativa, e informe também a linguagem, aproveite e leia [ask].